# While loop not exiting after condition met (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I'm not a skillful programmer by any means, but everyone's got to start somewhere.
I've been trying to make a (very) basic maze-type in ruby, but I'm having difficulty with the while loop not exiting.

Room layout is an upside down t:

```
 5
 2
103
 4
```

Going north twice from the center should change @loc to 5, say "End", and exit the loop:

```
elsif @loc == 2
@loc = 5
puts "End"
```

But it returns to the beginning of the while loop, stranding the player.

EDIT: there's some confusion about the code, so I'm removing the block and pointing you to 
http://pastebin.com/EFWVBAhn

Comment: We need to see more of your code. What are your classes? Most likely in your `cmd.go_north` you're accessing the `@loc` field of `cmd`, not of whatever your maze class is. But we can't tell until we see the code.

Comment: How do you expect the while statement to exit while `@loc`'s value isn't changing? Try checking the value of that variable at the beggining of the statement with a `puts` or something.

Comment: Please indent, especially when troubleshooting loops!  And it never exits because `@loc` is never `5`. But you haven't posted the code where `@loc` changes, so it's hard to say what the problem is.

Comment: I added debug code to my working copy and can confirm that @loc is getting changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
while @loc != 5
```

is accessing a variable which is not being changed. The changes are happening to `cmd.loc`, which is not the same variable. That line needs to be

```
while cmd.loc != 5
```

in order to access the variable.

Also you need to quote your strings (e.g. `if command == west` should be `if command == "west"`); otherwise you're telling Ruby to compare to a variable called `west`, which doesn't exist, rather than the string "west".

Comment: I did make that mistake with the strings, but it was corrected. I just forgot to recopy it.

Comment: puts @loc returns 5 for the expected space, so that should not the issue.

Comment: Where is the line `puts @loc`?